# Support for marathi language

Tags: android, localization

All my texts are in `string.xml` files which in turn contained in the folders `values-hi, values-en`. how to specify Locale marathi or please let me know the language specifier for values folder to fetch marathi strings

```
public void setLanguage(String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    Locale.getAvailableLocales();
    if (checkForLocaleSupport(locale)) {
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

}

public boolean checkLocaleSupport(Locale locale){
    Locale[] locs= Locale.getAvailableLocales();
    for(Locale l:locs){
        if(l.equals(locale)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

In oncreate() method of my main activity im setting language as setLanguage("hi") before setting the content. then after setting the content and intilisizing a textview im doing mHeaderText.setText(R.string.my_header); my header is read from string.xml in values-hi folder. but if I set language as "mr" , string is not fetched from values-mr folder. Greatly appreciate the help

Comment: to try to answer your question i am currently reading this doc http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes i found marathi

Comment: @adi give me method of checkForLocaleSupport() in above code

Comment: @dipali I have added the method. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it shoudl be `values-mr` for your folder from the 2 links I gave you in comments.

Edit: relevant links :
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes

Comment: Thanks @Poutrathor it worked wen I removed the check for locale support. I think the device I was using didn hav support for "mr" locale

Comment: ah, good to hear. I understand these lines  `It is also a mistake to assume that all devices have the same locales available. A device sold in the US will almost certainly support en_US and es_US, but not necessarily any locales with the same language but different countries (such as en_GB or es_ES), nor any locales for other languages (such as de_DE). The opposite may well be true for a device sold in Europe.` as the support for locale depends on the device manufacturer, not Android but I am not sure.

Comment: I put them in my comments. I add them right now in the answer