# My app's language is not changing after changing the device language

Tags: android, xml, localization

I am translating my app to the Marathi language. I've made the value-mr-rIN/strings.xml for the Marathi language. 
When I change my device language to Marathi the app still uses the default strings.xml which is English instead of using the values-mr-rIN/strings.xml.
What's the problem? I tried testing it on other devices still it shows English strings. I am pasting the code below

*values/strings.xml*

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
 <string name="app_name">App name</string>
 <string name="test">this is a test</string>
 </resources>
```

*values-mr-rIN/strings.xml*

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
 <string name="app_name">अॅप नाव</string>
 <string name="test">हे एक चाचणी आहे</string>
 </resources>
```

Comment: Does u change the app language using locale?

Comment: Did you restart your application after changed language? Because you should do it to make it work.

Comment: @ShubhamSejpal Yes, using the android studio's locale quantifier.

Comment: @TruongHieu Yes I did restart my app.

Comment: @0X0nosugar I've added more explanation on why my question is different. Please remove the flag.

Comment: Can you add your language change coding for briefly explanation?

Comment: I agree, your question is no duplicate. Since OP from the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238978/support-for-marathi-language) managed to at least use Hindi strings, I'm wondering whether you created your *values-hi* and *values-mr* folders as siblings of the *values* folder?

Comment: @0X0nosugar Yes, All the three folders _values-mr_, _values-hi_ and _values_ are in _res_.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Support for marathi language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238978/support-for-marathi-language)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A single line of code in gradle was causing this issue.

```
defaultConfig {
    ..
    resConfigs "en"
}
```

The above line in gradle means use only English language resource. Which is used to save space by removing other language resources from the app.
I changed it to..

```
 defaultConfig {
    ..
    resConfigs "en" ,"mr"
}
```

Now it uses English or Marathi resources with respect to the device language.

Comment: Perfect answer.Thanks.

Comment: superb perfect! So for us it was working on some devices and not on others. And found out this was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

May this helps you:-

just change your folder name
**values-mr/strings.xml**

To

**values-mr-rIN/string.xml**

After making this change it will work 100%.

See Demo Example:

[image]

Regular string.xml **Output**:-

[image]

**Marathi** string.xml **Output**:-

[image]